# How to close an AWS S3 read stream (AWSJavaScriptSDK)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS S3 object and a read stream created on it like this:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const readStream = s3
  .getObject(params)
  .createReadStream()
  .on('error', err => {
    // do something
  });
```

Now when the stream is not read to the end (e.g. the streaming is aborted by client) after 120 sec the `error` event is triggered with: `TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 120000ms`

How can I close the stream (or the entire S3 object)?

I tried `readStream.destroy()` that is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_destroy_error), but it does not work.

Comment: You can use `readStream.close()` or `.on('close', function (err) { console.log("closing stream.")})`

Comment: thanks, but when I use `readStream.close()` I get a `TypeError: readStream.close is not a function` error

Comment: maybe you are using the latest version of node, so then `readStream.destroy()` is the only way. If needed try `.end()` but i didn't recommend it.

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm trying to run `end()` but no affect.
In my case processing file of 600Mb.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for a solution to a similar case and bumped into this thread.

There is an [AWS Request `abort` method documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#abort-property) which allows you to cancel the request without receiving all the data (it's a similar concept to node's http request).

Your code should look somewhat like this:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const request = s3.getObject(params);
const readStream = request.createReadStream()
  .on('error', err => {
    request.abort(); // and do something else also...
  });
```

It may be on error, but in my case - I'm fetching data and I want to stop streaming when I've reached a certain point (i.e. found specific data in the file and it's only a matter of checking if it exists - I don't need anything else).

The above will work well with both `request` and `node-fetch` modules as well.